# Best way to validate input on keyup or blur

Tags: javascript, angular

I am validating user inputs I am a bit confused about which is the best way to implement validations. here I have prepared regex for the number with the decimal points.

.ts part

```
 checkIsNumber(event) {
    console.log('event', event.target.value);
    console.log('this.parcelResultDetails.bidperacre', this.parcelResultDetails.bidperacre);
    const regix = new RegExp(/^\d*\.?\d+$/);
    const result = regix.test(event.target.value);
    if (result) {
      this.parcelResultDetails.bidperacre = event.target.value;
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    return result;
  }
```

.html

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="twp" class="ldes-lb-clr ">Amount($)</label>
      <input #twp class="form-control" placeholder="Parcel" type="text"
        [ngModel]="parcelResultDetails.bidperacre" (keyup)="checkIsNumber($event)">
    </div>
```

**here I am using keyup for the validations in angular app.**

Question: Which is the standard way to check data validations between blur and keyup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that this is a really basic answer, but validating on keyup could annoy the user, but still it really depends on the situation, in my case, i would consider validating from submit reaching keyup according to information sensitivity as a standard.

A similar answer was given on a similar question on stackexchange [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/48268/validate-on-blur-or-keypress).